# FunGen in Ubuntu

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, freeglut

I've just installed Ubuntu succesfully, mainly to make it easier to work Haskell libraries than in Windows.

When I run some Haskell code I was working on, it just knocks my socks off. I'm using FunGen libraries for my game and I got this error when I tried to run it.

```
freeglut (FunGen app):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities nt found> in function fgOpenWindow
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
```

After some web searching, I found a way to fix this in C code, (using `GlutDouble` instead of `GlDouble`), and I am using the type `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GLdouble` in my Haskell code.

a liitle more research told me that type GlDouble = Double, so , this isn't the cause, in addition, i just took off the gldouble part in code and still it does not work.
So, here is some simple code that drive me to the previous error:

```
module Main where
import Graphics.UI.Fungen
width, height :: Int
width = 600
height = 400
w = fromIntegral width
h = fromIntegral height

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let winConfig = ((200, 200), (width, height), "game");
        gameMap = (textureMap 0 w h w h);
    funInit winConfig gameMap [] () () [] gameCycle (Timer 30) []
gameCycle :: IOGame () () () () ()
gameCycle = do  
            showFPS TimesRoman24 (w-40,0) 1.0 0.0 0.0
```

about versions, ive got : freeglut3 2.6.0-1ubuntu2, ghc 6.12.3, fungen 0.3 ,haskell glut 2.2.2.0 and ubuntu 11.04

Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: Is there a small (under 30 lines or so) code snippet that we could use to reproduce this problem ourselves?

Comment: Don't forget to include version information (GHC, freeglut, FunGen, Haskell GLUT library, etc)

Comment: I could not find any `GlutDouble` when searching around for this. However, `GLUT_DOUBLE` is used to enable double buffering, which would seem to be related as this would appear to be an initialization problem, and not anything related to floating-point types. I've tried to clean up your question a little, but some additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions!! i found this place my second univesity :P
and thanks hammar for your editions, my english is not any good :P

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but skimming https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24226 and http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-333966.html makes it sound like you might get results by trying different GL[UT] initialization parameters. See [FunGEn's Graphics/UI/Fungen/Init.hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/FunGEn/0.3/doc/html/src/Graphics-UI-Fungen-Init.html#funInit), and [GLUT's initialization api](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/GLUT/2.2.2.0/doc/html/Graphics-UI-GLUT-Initialization.html). Maybe have FunGEn's `funInit` explicitly set indirect mode:

```
initialize "FunGen app" ["-indirect"]
```

Comment: this seems pretty awesome!
im seeing how to re install the modifications, i hope it helps me!!

Comment: `darcs get http://joyful.com/repos/fungen`, 
`cd fungen`,
edit Graphics/UI/Fungen/Init.hs,
`cabal install` and then go rebuild your own project (or, build your project with `-ipath_to_fungen_src_dir`).

Comment: I had forgotten the -ipath. 
Anyway it dindt worked. I hate that i must swicth to Windows to make it work u.u
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't give up, talk to the relevant package maintainers, it's supposed to work. As a data point, it works for me with these versions:
    ubuntu maverick,
    freeglut3 2.6.0-0ubuntu2,
    libglu1-mesa 7.9~git20100924-0ubuntu,
    OpenGL-2.4.0.1,
    GLUT-2.2.2.0,
    GHC 7.0.2